# Xcode: Using XCConfig keys in plist other than Info.Plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, info.plist

I created an xcconfig file and am trying to use the keys inside `Info.plist`.
But I am not able to use it in other plist files.
For example Auth0 has its own `plist` and the keys inside `Auth0.plist` don't pick up values from the XCConfig file. Instead I end up just getting the key.

For e.g. This is in my XCConfig File.
`AUTH_CLIENT_ID = abcdefgh12345678`
And the Plist contains - `ClientId` as key and `$(AUTH_CLIENT_ID)` as Value.

But on accessing the `ClientId` from `Auth0.plist`, I get "`$(AUTH_CLIENT_ID)`" as a String instead of `abcdefgh12345678`

Comment: I think you are supposed to put key/value in the `info.plist`instead of a secondary plist.

Comment: Well, the Auth0's pod uses this `Auth0.plist.` I dont want to make changes inside the pod.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: Nope. Did not find a way. Wrote a run script to copy the plist in the bundle.